# Error encountered with a mysql sql file during command execute

Tags: mysql, vb.net

The below code works when in a MySql SQL editor:

```sql
SELECT currentqty INTO @cqty from items where itemid = 'FELABELS';

set @aqty = @cqty + 10;

UPDATE ITEMS 
SET CURRENTQTY = @aqty
WHERE ITEMID = 'FELABELS';
```

but in the VB.NET application where I have the above code in a .sql file and pass it to the command to execute I get an error "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

Sql file contents:

```sql
SELECT currentqty INTO @cqty from items where itemid = @ItemId;

set @aqty = @cqty + @Qty;

UPDATE ITEMS 
SET CURRENTQTY = @aqty
WHERE ITEMID = @ItemId;
```

Class where it executed, the `_sqlText` will be contents of the .sql file:

```
   Using mdscmd = New MySqlCommand(_sqlText, MyConnection) With {
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text}

        mdscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Quantity)
        mdscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemId", ItemId)

        Try
            mdscmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception

            End Using
            Return False
        End Try

    End Using
```

Anyone see an issue?

Comment: [Executing Multiple Non-SELECT MySQL Statements as a Single Command Text in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481632/executing-multiple-non-select-mysql-statements-as-a-single-command-text-in-net) could be what you're asking. Also, just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: adding this to the connection string fixed issue. allowbatch=true;allowuservariables=true;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing Multiple Non-SELECT MySQL Statements as a Single Command Text in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481632/executing-multiple-non-select-mysql-statements-as-a-single-command-text-in-net)

Comment: Yes, that is where I got the connection string info from.

Comment: There should be somewhere you can tick to say you agree that this question is a duplicate: [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) It helps to keep the site tidy.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SELECT currentqty INTO @cqty from items where itemid = 'FELABELS';
>
> set @aqty = @cqty + 10;
>
> UPDATE ITEMS  SET CURRENTQTY = @aqty WHERE ITEMID = 'FELABELS';
> ```

This code is deterministic only when `itemid` is unique.

Assuming this is true I'd recommend to combine these 3 queries to single

```
UPDATE items 
SET currentqty = currentqty + 10
WHERE itemid = 'FELABELS';
```